# Is there a way to vectorize calculations that use data from other dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I am trying to optimize a for loop that currently takes ~8 hours to run. I have recently learned about Vectorization, and would like to take advantage of this feature to speed up my code.

I have a dataframe (df) that has and index of days (1-250), and columns for each years.
In my current code, I create a new empty dataframe (rdf) to hold the results of several metrics I need to calculate on this data.

```
In [155]: df
Out[155]: 
Year   2007   2008   2009    2010  ...    2018    2019    2020    2021
Day                                   ...                                
1            -0.380 -0.050 -0.050 -0.2100  ... -0.1150 -0.2950 -0.1200 -0.1150
2            -0.360 -0.030 -0.050 -0.1900  ... -0.1150 -0.3050 -0.1300 -0.1100
3            -0.360 -0.040 -0.050 -0.1950  ... -0.1100 -0.3050 -0.1350 -0.1100
4            -0.340 -0.040 -0.050 -0.1950  ... -0.1175 -0.3100 -0.1350 -0.1150
5            -0.350 -0.030 -0.055 -0.2000  ... -0.1200 -0.3100 -0.1450 -0.1200
...             ...    ...    ...     ...  ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
246          -0.600  0.005 -0.530  0.0925  ... -0.1650 -0.1325 -0.1550 -0.0750
247          -0.700  0.020 -0.565  0.0900  ... -0.1875 -0.1075 -0.1500 -0.0700
248          -0.700  0.010 -0.615  0.0700  ... -0.2125 -0.0700 -0.1550 -0.0050
249          -0.700 -0.020 -0.630  0.1250  ... -0.2300 -0.0675 -0.1700  0.0025
250          -0.628  0.010 -0.420  0.1819  ... -0.2300 -0.0625 -0.1725 -0.0200
```

I then need to loop through each day in df (start day), and each possible end day (which is every day > the start day) to calculate the metrics.

```
count=0
for startDay in range(df.index.min(), df.index.max()+1):
    for endDay in range(df.index.min()+1, df.index.max()+1):
        
        inDatePrice = df.loc[df.index[starDay-1]]
        peakAfterEntry = df.loc[df.index[starDay:endDay]].max()
        inDatePriceToPeak = peakAfterEntry - inDatePrice
     
        rdf.iloc[[count],0] = startDay
        rdf.iloc[[count],1] = endDay
        rdf.iloc[[count],2] = inDatePrice
        rdf.iloc[[count],3] = inDatePriceToPeak
        
        count+=1
```

Above is my for loop  and an example of the metrics I need to calculate. There are 18 metrics total.
Is there a way to vectorize these calculations?